# Win + mouse wheel keeps showing/hiding start menu

Tags: autohotkey

I wanted to add volume control to my mouse with the following scripts

```
#WheelUp::
Send {Volume_Up}
Return

#WheelDown::
Send {Volume_Down}
Return
```

However, when I use it, the start menu keeps appearing/disappearing. Is there anyway to consistently suppress the windows key with this script?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to recreate your problem, but the code works on my machine. If I hold the Windows key down and use the mousewheel it adjusts the volume (Windows 10). You might be having problems with a competing command that you are running at the same time.

Also, the line breaks and return statements are unnecessary. It also works as:

```
#WheelUp::Send {Volume_Up}
#WheelDown::Send {Volume_Down}
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I am running classic shell.  That's probably the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Function SoundSet, apparently doesn't cause this issue:

```
#WheelUp::
SoundSet, +2
Return

#WheelDown::
SoundSet, -2
Return
```